# Is ( ¬p AND (p OR q) ) AND ¬q a contradiction?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

As We Know That

```
p AND (q OR r) = (p AND q)OR(p AND r)
```

we have

```
= ((¬p AND p) OR (¬p AND q)) AND ¬q

= (F OR (¬p AND q)) AND ¬q

= (¬p AND q) AND (q AND ¬q)

=F
```

hence a contradiction

i do not understand these two steps

```
(F OR (¬p AND q)) AND ¬q

(¬p AND q) AND (q AND ¬q)
```

can someone please explain these two steps .. what rule is applied and what is going on here ?  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to use the following notation for AND, OR, and F respectively: $\land, \lor, \bot$.

$$(\bot\;\lor\;(\neg P\;\land\;q))\land\neg q\iff(\neg P\;\land\;q)\land\neg q$$

A formal elimination rule isn't being used here, but rather, the theorem:

$$\bot\lor P\iff P$$

Think about it with truth tables (semantically). Since $Q\lor P$ is true only when either $Q$ or $P$ (or both) are true, if $Q=\bot$, then $Q\lor P$ is only true if $P$ is true, and hence false if $P$ is false. So $\bot\lor P\iff P$.

The last step follows from $q\land\neg q$ always being false (law of excluded middle) and $P\land \bot\implies\bot$.

In summary, formally prove these three lemmas:

1. $\bot\lor P\iff P$
2. $P\land\neg P\implies\bot$
3. $P\land \bot\implies\bot$

Answer (score 0):

It is probably simpler to use the associative/commutative laws to collect the negated terms and then use De Morgan's rule once to get a contradiction directly:
$$ (\neg p \land (p \lor q)) \land \neg q  \;\equiv\;
  (\neg p \land \neg q) \land (p \lor q) \;\equiv\;
  \neg(p\lor q) \land (p\lor q) $$